# AG listener Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, always-on-top, alwayson

I created AG group on SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU8 on windows 2016 core edition. However, I am unable to connect using AG Listener name. what could be the possible reasons? I can ping and telnet static IP and Listener DNS name from my local machine even though I am unable to connect to the listener using local SSMS or SQLCMD on the server.

Note: I can connect to the named instance name. SQL ports are open and network related settings like Browser, named pipes, tcp.ip and allow remote connections are enabled. I also double checked with the network guys about the ports and IP. SQL Services are running on service account. Everything is clear. BUT :( NO LUCK.

Error:

> SQL Server Error 2 code not open connection

Comment: What if you also specify the port number (which should force the client to use TCP)?

Comment: Ben, 

Connected to AG listener. Thank you so much. Is it mandatory to specify the port number?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Normally, it's the SQL Browser service that does an instance → port mapping (in much the same way that DNS does a name → IP mapping). It requires that UDP 1434 is open for communication.

Comment: Oh, I see then I will check with network team. Thanks, Ben.